# Is a group authority in Spring Security 3 simply a shortcut for grouping several roles into one?

Tags: spring-security

Every forum post or tutorial I can find appears to address groups and group authorities differently. The reference for Spring Security indicates that groups are simply a shortcut for grouping several authorities (roles) into one. For instance, a group of "Administrators" might have ROLE_USER, ROLE_MANAGE_USER, while a group of "Users" might only have ROLE_USER. Is that the correct way to think about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct way to think about it - groups are simply a shortcut for aggregating a number of GrantedAuthority values into a logical group.

Contrast this with the more complex capability of the Spring Security ACL module, which does have the more abstract concept of group membership that you could apply in a given situation.

Hope that answers your question!